# Responsive sizing and positioning of multiple images relatively to another in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to put some images over another one (which is a big logo), and I also want it to be responsive : when I reduce the size of the browser window, I want the images that are over the logo to stay at the same place on the logo and follow its automatic resizing.

Here is what I have in the browser for now (I want to have the images on the lines and don't move from their position even when reducing the window) :
[browser actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pqtb.png)

And here is the code I have done until now :

```css
#frame {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo-canvas {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.parent-photo {
    position: relative;
}

#child-photo1 {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;

}

#child-photo2 {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2rem;
    top: 2rem;

}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="frame" class="parent-photo">
    <img id="logo-canvas"src="assets/images/salmon-logo.png" alt="Wild Logo Shape">
      <!--<div id="parent-photo"> -->
    <img id="child-photo1" src="assets/images/Lorem-Ipsum-alternatives.png" alt="Photo 1">
    <img id="child-photo2" src="assets/images/Lorem-Ipsum-alternatives.png" alt="Photo 2">
      <!--</div> -->
  </div>
</section>
```

I thought that the parent/child relation with the position attribute would work, but I am stuck (maybe the flex is messing with it ?). I am still a beginner so I could really use some help !

Thank you to anyone who will help me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, it can be really difficult to do what you describe and have it work well for all viewports.

If you want to give it a try though, try using vw units to position and resize the child images, then they'll respond to the viewport or screen width.

To get you started, see what this looks like:

```
#child-photo1 {
    width: 5.5vw;
    height: 5.5vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1.375vw;
    top: 1.375vw;

}

#child-photo2 {
    width: 5.5vw;
    height: 5.5vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2.75vw;
    top: 2.75vw;
}
```

Don't be surprised if the images get too small at some mobile views, and too large on some desktop views. If this is the case you could set max-width,max-height, min-width, min-height values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sadly the change of units didn't really helped, it even made my photos move even more with the change of screen size.

For now I used different "media screen" to define different positions for all the photos at different screen sizes. It is not ideal at all but as this display is only for desktop screens (it is simplified below 1024px), it is enough for now.

I will look for other solutions in the future (maybe in Javascript and/or with React or another framework ?...).

Answer (score 0):

영어를 잘 못해서 한글로 적어요.
원하는 이미지들을 png로 동일한 크기로 만든 후 부모 태그 역시 동일한 크기로 설정하고 position을 relative로 잡는다. 자식에 있는 해당 이미지들을 absolute, max-width:100%로 설정 한다.
마지막으로 해당 이미지들을 top, left 등등 퍼센트로 잡아 주면 된다.

(I am not good at English, so I use Google Translation. After making the desired images the same size with png, the parent tag is also set to the same size and the position is relative. Set the corresponding images in the child to absolute, max-width:100%.
Finally, you can set the images as top, left, etc. percentages.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).